# TypeError: divide() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Tags: tensorflow

I have a tensor of size `m * n` and a vector of size `n`.  I want to divide each value of the first column of `x` by the first value of `y` and so on.

It seems that tensorflow does not support `tf.divide((x,y), axis=...)`. How can I do that?

I tried using `tf.divide((x, y), axis=0)` but it produced an error.

Comment: Grammar and highlighting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TensorFlow basic operations support [broadcasting](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_guides/python/math_ops#arithmetic-operators):

```
import tensor flow as tf
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
B = np.array([2, 2])
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
d = a / b
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(d, {a:A, b:B}))

[[0.5 1. ]
[1.5 2. ]
[2.5 3. ]]
```

If you reshape `B`, it would work as well:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1., 2], [3, 4.], [5, 6]])
B = np.array([1., 2., 3.]).reshape((3,1))
a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
d = a / b

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(d, {a:A, b:B}))
```